# During XML exception processing, how do I get the line number in the XML file that's causing the exception?

Tags: c#, xml, exception

This question might sound similar to other question in Stack Overflow, but is different.

I am trying to load an XML file using `new XmlDocument()` & `LoadXml()`. While doing so there are some xml tags that are incomplete or incorrect and due to it is throwing exception. I want to make a list of them. Now I want this line number from `exception` object:

[image]

I want to extract line number pointed with RED arrow (which I thought would be `ex.LineNumber`, but it is not). I can extract from `ex.Message` (highlighted with YELLOW), but if it is available (like the place marked with RED arrow) then I would like to figure out how to get that value. Or is it not possible?

**More clarification:** Also if you look at `StackTrace` then you might find that that is another line number (**Line 47**) mentioned in the end but that's not what I am looking for (shown below).

```
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowTagMismatch(NodeData startTag)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEndElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
   at <ProjectName>.Program.EvaluateEpisodeList(String strSeriesHomePageCode) in C:\<Path>\<ProjectName>\Program.cs:line 47
```

Hope this clarifies my question.

Most of the similar question on internet is for extracting line number from `StackTrace`, I didn't find anything that would solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *which I thought would be ex.LineNumber, but it is not* **yes, it is** ... but no in Exception class but derived from it .. check the EXACT type of this exeption and cast to it(or use EXACT type of this exception in catch) ...edit: prolly this is XmlException

Comment: Hope you don't mind but I updated your question's title to reflect and be in sync with that you are seeking the line number from the _XML file_ (which you nicely explain in the question's body itself).  Helps future readers and search engines :)

Comment: Thanks @MickyD, this is much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

**Edit:** I have completely misunderstood your question. here is the answer:

---

Catch an `XmlException` **instead** of a *general exception*. Then you can get the line number with `e.LineNumber`.

MSDN has this to say on `LineNumber` (my emphasis):

> Gets the line number indicating where the error occurred. **Line numbers start at 1.** 
>  
> Attempting to load the string "<\r\nbar" as XML throws an XmlException with the following message:
> System.Xml.XmlException: 'Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C. Line 1, position 2.'
> Showing that line number is 1-based (the error is found in the first line).  *[Tell me more...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlexception.linenumber?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_XmlException_LineNumber)*

Like this:

```
try
{
    // Load XML here
} 
catch (XmlException e) // <-----
{
    Console.WriteLine("Line: " + e.LineNumber);
}
```

### More

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlexception.linenumber?view=net-5.0) is the documentation, you have probably found it already:

- [XmlException.LineNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlexception.linenumber?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Quick question - what made you confused. Can I make my question any better for future users?

Comment: It is great that you ask. I just missread, it is 2 am where I live. :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe it can be useful..

[Exception class and properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/exception-class-and-properties)

or

```
catch (XmlException ex) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Line: "+ex.LineNumber);
//or
    MessageBox.Show($"Line: {ex.LineNumber}")
}
```

Comment: `Exception` class does not expose a `LineNumber` property sadly